# Javascript not reading array items beginning with 0

Tags: javascript

I want to give genetic algorithms a chance but I can't seem to find a solution for this problem.

This is my code:

```js
var encodings = {
  0000: 0,
  0001: 1,
  0010: 2,
  0011: 3,
  0100: 4,
  0101: 5,
  0110: 6,
  0111: 7,
  1000: 8,
  1001: 9,
  1010: "+",
  1011: "-",
  1100: "*",
  1101: "/"
};
var chromosome = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
  chromosome += Math.round(Math.random());
}

var chromArray = chromosome.match(/.{1,4}/g);

document.write(chromArray + "<br>");

for (var o = 0; o < 9; o++) {
  document.write(encodings[chromArray[o]]);
}
```

If you run the code, you see that there are a lot of undefineds in the output.
What would cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: how do you handle "1110" in you chromosome?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers

Comment: @Thomas If a string generated with 1110 or 1111 the string wont be part of the initial population, the idea is to only add chromosomes to the population who follow the "number - operator - number" rule.

Comment: that's not how the code works, you show; it generates a random sequence of ones and zeroes, and tries to map them to matching entities. My point is: your code has some major flaws in the implementation, and even without them there's not much of an genetic algorithm you're going after; you're just building some String shuffling. **Rethink your concept**, it leads nowhere really productive at the moment.

Comment: @Thomas I know what I write and there is no reason to rethink my concept because you're concluding something even though you haven't seen my whole code. I don't know what I did to earn your demotivating words but it sure doesn't belong here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should convert the keys of the object into strings

It should be:

```
var encodings = 
{
  "0000": 0,
  "0001": 1,
  "0010": 2,
  "0011": 3,
  "0100": 4,
  "0101": 5,
  "0110": 6,
  "0111": 7,
  "1000": 8,
  "1001": 9,
  "1010": "+",
  "1011": "-",
  "1100": "*",
  "1101": "/"
};

var chromosome = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) 
{
  chromosome += Math.round(Math.random());
}

var chromArray = chromosome.match(/.{1,4}/g);

document.write(chromArray + "<br>");

for (var o = 0; o < 9; o++) 
{
  document.write(encodings[chromArray[o]]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The keys of the object in which the number starts with `0` you should convert into the strings

If you print the `encodings` you will see the problem. JavaScript decoded the numbers that start with `0` as octal number.

```js
var encodings = {
    0000: 0,
    0001: 1,
    0010: 2,
    0011: 3,
    0100: 4,
    0101: 5,
    0110: 6,
    0111: 7,
    1000: 8,
    1001: 9,
    1010: "+",
    1011: "-",
    1100: "*",
    1101: "/"
};


document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(encodings, 0, 2) + '</pre>')
```